# Spring boot page refresh has some 404 requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, http-status-code-404

I am on login page of my project. It is `spring boot` + `thymeleaf - HTML`.

At chrome network tab, when I refresh, I only see status of 200. There are no 404.

But project logs show, 2 requests are coming to 404 handling. By the way, despite those errors, page does not have any errors.

```
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";
@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return ERROR_PATH;
}


    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        GenericService.logger.error("handleError. Redirecting to /error, status: {}", request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE));
        return "error-404";
    }
```

So, i see that 2 times when I refresh the page:

```
handleError. Redirecting to /error, status: 404
```

This is login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <!-- Site favicon -->
    <link href='/internals/images/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!-- /site favicon -->
 <script src="/internals/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/internals/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="login-page">

            <form method="post" th:action="@{/authenticateTheUser}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">E-Mail</label>:
                    <input autofocus="autofocus"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="username"
                           name="username"
                           placeholder="E-Mail"
                           type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Şifre</label>:
                    <input class="form-control"
                           id="password"
                           name="password"
                           placeholder="Password"
                           type="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Giriş Yap</button>
                </div>

            </form>

    <!--Load JQuery-->
    <script src="/internals/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/internals/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I see which URL is causing to go to 404 handling? Inside, I can not see from request.

What do you suggest?

`.loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")` but i dont use button. I only refresh page –

Comment: Do you have an /authenticateTheUser mapping in any controller?

Comment: @Jorge.V yes  .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser") but i dont use button.  I only refresh page

Comment: Might be some static resource import. Can you open the console on your browser and see if it is getting some 404's for files?

Comment: @Jorge.V as i wrote, there are no 404 errors. All of them have 200